# PHPUnit Strange behavior when mocking MongoCollection

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

Assume I have this test:

```
public function testStorage()
{
    $collection = $this->getMockBuilder('MongoCollection')->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();

    $collection->method('findOne')->will($this->returnValueMap([
        [['_id' => 'aaa'], ['content'], 'ccc'],
    ]));

    $this->assertEquals('ccc', $collection->findOne(['_id' => 'aaa'], ['content']));
}
```

When running unit test it says: Failed asserting that null matches expected 'ccc'.
I couldn't figure out why. But if I switch to mock another function, let's say: find it should work.

```
public function testStorage()
{
    $collection = $this->getMockBuilder('MongoCollection')->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();

    $collection->method('find')->will($this->returnValueMap([
        [['_id' => 'aaa'], ['content'], 'ccc'],
    ]));

    $this->assertEquals('ccc', $collection->find(['_id' => 'aaa'], ['content']));
}
```

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)

I really appreciate your help! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I use getMock and it's work for me:

```
$collection = $this->getMock('MongoCollection', ['find', 'findOne'], [], '', false);
        $collection->method('find')->will($this->returnValue([
                [['_id' => 'aaa'], ['content'], 'ccc']
            ]));
        $collection->method('findOne')->will($this->returnValue([
            [['_id' => 'aaa'], ['content'], 'ccc']
        ]));
```